# Can I use CNN For EMG signals?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, signals, signal-processing

I have raw data EMG signals which it's represented in 1 column. Can I use CNN model to extract features from this column?

Comment: Looks like [others did](https://www.google.com/search?q=emg+cnn)...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.